# How to download the docker image that Azure pipeline built for dotnet 7?

Tags: .net, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, .net-7.0

I have an Azure pipeline that uses new dotnet 7 functionality with built-in docker image build support, using the dotnet cli `dotnet publish -c Release --os linux --arch x64 /t:PublishContainer`. It succeeds, and proceeds to inform me that `Pushed container 'testApp:1.0.0' to Docker daemon`.

How do I access it? On my local machine I can save it as tar, not sure what's the process to do so on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the image is pushed to the local machine's Docker daemon. In that case, that's the pipeline agent. To have the image pushed to an external registry, you can set the `ContainerRegistry` project property:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ContainerRegistry>registry.mycorp.com</ContainerRegistry>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is documented at https://github.com/dotnet/sdk-container-builds/blob/6da3967241627967be7dc025382f7dc343a8a6a9/docs/ContainerCustomization.md#containerregistry

You'll need to ensure the pipeline agent has authenticated to the target registry before executing the publish operation. For example: `docker login registry.mycorp.com`

More documentation on registry authentication in the context of .NET SDK container builds is at https://github.com/dotnet/sdk-container-builds/blob/6da3967241627967be7dc025382f7dc343a8a6a9/docs/RegistryAuthentication.md

Once the image has been pushed to the external registry, you can then pull it from another machine, for example: `docker pull registry.mycorp.com/testApp:1.0.0`